# Application of chain rule, is this correct?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing, radon-nikodym

I have $\sigma$ finite measures $\lambda$ and $\mu$ on the same space $(X, \Sigma)$, and $\nu = \lambda + \mu$. An exercise I have is to show that 
$\lambda \ll \mu$ if and only if $$\nu(\{d\mu/d\nu(x) = 0\}) = 0$$

---

To show $\rightarrow$ direction, I think

$$\nu(\{d\mu/d\nu(x) = 0\}) = \lambda(\{d\mu/d\nu(x) = 0\}) + \mu(\{d\mu/d\nu(x) = 0\})$$

and  second term is 0 because

$$
\mu(\{d\mu/d\nu(x) = 0\}) = \int_{\{d\mu/d\nu(x) = 0\}}(d\mu/d\nu)d\nu
$$

so we are taking it over the space where it is 0. The first term I thought I could use Chain rule like

$$
\lambda(\{d\mu/d\nu(x) = 0\}) = \int_{\{d\mu/d\nu(x) = 0\}} (d\lambda/d\nu)d\nu = \int_{\{d\mu/d\nu(x) = 0\}} (d\lambda/d\mu)(d\mu/d\nu)d\nu
$$

.. but my question is - is this a good idea? If it is okay, then how do I make it formal that this term is $0$? Does it simplify to

$$
\int_{\{d\mu/d\nu(x) = 0\}} (d\lambda/d\mu)(d\mu/d\nu)d\nu = (d\lambda/d\mu)(0)
$$

or am I not understanding right? I mostly just don't know if pulling things out like this is allowed. Also, ideas for $\leftarrow$ way would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: In my answer I am assuming that your measures are all positive measures. If they are signed measures or complex measures the validity of the statement looks doubtful.  General piece of advice: use chain rule when you already have absolute continuity. When singular parts are present write down Lebesgue decomposition before using RN derivatives (as I have done in the converse part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you use the fact that $\lambda << \mu$?. In the second line of your proof you already know that second term is 0. The first term is 0 because of the hypothesis that $\lambda << \mu$? (Just the definition of absolute continuity, right?). For the reverse implication let $\mu =\mu_1+\mu_2$ be the Lebesgue decomposition of $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$. To show that $\lambda << \mu$ it is enough to show that $\lambda << \mu_1$ (because $\mu_1 \leq \mu$). If $\mu_1 (E)=0$ then $\int_E \frac {d\mu_1} {d\nu} d\nu=0$. But we are assuming that $\frac {d\mu_1} {d\nu} >0$ almost everywhere with respect to $\nu$. Hence $\nu (E)=0$. But $\lambda \leq \nu$ so we get $\lambda (E)=0$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me. One thing I do not understand - you say "The first term is 0 because of the hypothesis that λ<<μ"? How does it just follow from that? I don't need chain rule?

Comment: By definition of absolute continuity $\mu (E)=0$ implies $\lambda (E)=0$. Take $E=\{d\mu /d\nu (x)=0\}$.